# Lookup headers and use COUNTA to sum the data under it

Tags: excel-formula, subtotal

I am trying to find a specific column based on month (`B1`) and count the number of cells with `x` under it based on by the designated region (`D1`).

[image: data]

This is what I figured it would be but it is coming back as `#VALUE!`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,INDEX($1:$1048576,0,MATCH($B$1,$3:$3,‌​0))),--(($A:$A=D$1))‌​)
```

Comment: And you expect to get back 2, because there are 2 x's under July with Region = North?

Comment: Yes. 2 x's for July North.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUBTOTAL does not work with INDEX, use OFFSET:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A3,ROW(1:9),MATCH($B$1,3:3,0)-1))*(A4:A12=D1))
```

[image]

---

Edit

This version is dynamic:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A3,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MATCH("zzz",A:A)-3)),MATCH($B$1,3:3,0)-1))*(A4:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))=D1))
```

It will automatically resize based on how much data is in Column A.  It is set that the title row is in row 3, if that changes then you need to change the `3:3` and the `-3` to the row number where the titles are located.

Comment: I moved the formula to a different sheet but now it is coming up as #N/A what am I doing wrong? The above spreadsheet is on Data Sheet, B1 and A4 in the formula below is on the Results Sheet where the formula is located.                                                                                                   =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Data!$A$3,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MATCH("zzz",Data!$A:$A)-3)),MATCH(B1,Data!$3:$3,0)-1))*(Data!$A$4:INDEX(Data!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Data!$A:$A))=A4))